# Drop Down Button Change

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 dropdowns to which I have already assigned a macro (same macro to both dropdowns). The values in 1st dropdown are : {Feb, March, April, May}. The values in 2nd dropdown are: {sales volume, sales amount, profit }. Now I want to add one more functionality in my excel macro. When I select May from 1st dropdown, a vbok mssgbox should appear with a message. However, when May is already selected in 1st dropdown and we change values in 2nd dropdown, then the mssgbox should not appear again and again. As in, it should only appear with change in dropdown1. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a different macro for the first dropdown box. It only needs to perform the test for *May* and call the macro of the second dropdown box afterwards (or before the test - as you like).

Answer (score 0):

Since you've been able to assign one and the same macro to both drop-down boxes you must be using form controls and not ActiveX controls.

Hence, you can make use of the `Application.Caller` within the macro to find out which drop-down box caused the macro to run:

```
Sub SameMacroForTwoDropDownBoxes()

'The following line of code will tell you
'  in a message box which of the two
'  drop-down boxes initiated the macro
MsgBox Application.Caller

End Sub
```

With this you can change what's happening in the macro based on which of the two drop-down boxes has been changed:

```
Sub SameMacroForTwoDropDownBoxes()

'The following line of code will tell you
'  in a message box which of the two
'  drop-down boxes initiated the macro
Select Case Application.Caller
    Case "Drop Down 1"
        MsgBox "The first drop-down box has been changed."
    Case "Drop Down 2"
        MsgBox "The second drop-down box has been changed."
    Case Else
        MsgBox "No idea where this was coming from..."
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: @Gargi Nirmal, you should accept (click the button) his answer then. It shows to others that this solved your problem. It also generates reputation for the answerer and even a bit for yourself!